# Used {input = map(float, raw_input().split()).} How to accept if user input 1 float number?

Tags: split

I'm asking user to input their score and credit in one line, separated by a space, I've made it into a loop, so that when user enter -1, the program prints 'Program ends.'

```
input = map(float, raw_input().split())
gpa, credit = input

print 'Current GPA: %.2f' % gpa
while True:
    if input[0] != -1:
       input = map(float, raw_input().split())
       gpa = ((gpa * credit) + (input[0] * input[1])) / (credit + input[1])
       print 'Current GPA: %.2f' % gpa
    if input [0] == -1:
       print 'Program ends.'
       break
```

---

```
sample output: 
3.7 3
Current GPA: 3.70
3.3 2 
Current GPA: 3.54
-1
Program ends.
```

but I've got an error like this:

```
Output: 
3.7 3
Current GPA: 3.70
3.3 2 
Current GPA: 3.50
-1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tiffany/PycharmProjects/Labs/p3.py", line 8, in <module>
    gpa = ((gpa * credit) + (input[0] * input[1])) / (credit + input[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could someone please tell me how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: `input` is still a string when you check `input[0] != -1`. (Also, `input` is a bad variable name, because it clashes with the built-in function with the same name.)

Comment: Doesn't {input = map(float, raw_input().split())} change it to a float??

Comment: whoops - misread that. Inside the loop, you go straight from `input = map(float, raw_input().split())` to `gpa = ...` without checking whether the input was -1. (It looks like you're probably also forgetting to update `credit`.)

Comment: But my point is I want user to input '-1' to terminate the program. I know it won't be updating credit. That's the problem. So, is there another way to input 2 float number on the same line??

Comment: Instead of read input->try to use it->check whether you shouldn't have done that, check before you try to use it.

Comment: Then what should I use??